# How long the time function works in php

Tags: php, timestamp

Is php date() and time() function works between the years 1901-2038. What function will I use for my long based projects. or I am wrong?

Comment: You're worried about dates 29 years in the future already?!

Comment: by the year 2038, we would be coding parallelism-oriented programming in PZP language on 512-bits quantum computer with 64TB parametrized dynamic autonomous memory ... you should be more worried on whether you would still be alive to experience that ;)

Comment: owh btw we would all be running Google Soltice OS with neural networking support ... i can go crazy on this what-might-the-future-be stuff :P

Comment: I am not worried but I have a big doubt on this. Thank you for all who cleared my doubt.

Comment: @Lukman: yes. But from our track record, it seems likely that many embedded systems will still use 32-bit Unix timestamp. Y2K all over again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The timestamp only wraps around after January 19, 2038 on 32-bit systems. On 64-bit systems, this is not an issue, since most 64-bit operating systems use signed 64-bit integers for storing the timestamp. (With signed 64-bit integers, the timestamp wraps around on December 4, 292,277,026,596 AD.)

By 2038, I'd bet that most computer systems will be running on 64-bit architecture (at least), so it probably won't be a problem in the long run. Besides, there's nothing you yourself can do about it—it's an issue with the underlying operating system and processor architecture, not the code you write.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the [PEAR::Date](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.datetime.date.php) class, it can be used for dates **before 1970 and after 2038**.

Example:

```
require_once 'Date.php';

$longAgo = new Date('1813-02-23T05:34:23');

echo $longAgo->getTime();
echo $longAgo->getDate();
```

Maybe also the [The DateTime class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) can do it!?

Comment: I don't think this changes anything, since the underlying operating system is what is storing the time. PHP doesn't have anything to do with it, really.